# selectedimagetintcolor method xcode 5

Tags: colors, tabbar, selected, tint

i am new to ios development. I want to change the selected tab bar item's tint color in xcode 5.

I put this in TabBarController.h :

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIColor *selectedImageTintColor
```

then i put this code in .m file under view did load : `[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];`

but nothing happens ? i want to change the selected tab bar item's tint color in xcode 5 for ios 7. Thanks for any help and sorry for my bad English :(

Comment: Appears to be broken even in the GM builds

Comment: I second that it seems to be broken.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is definitely broken.  You can use`[self.tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"insert your image name here"]]` instead.  It will visually let the user know what tab they are on.